# Progressive Web App(PWA) from a Hybrid App : Storing Relational Offline Data

Tags: ios, sqlite, progressive-web-apps, offline, indexeddb

I have an hybrid app written in ionic 3. We have users on web and ios and supports offline (ios only)  using SQLite as a storage extension. SQLite stores around 500MB of relational data on an average for my use case. As part of modernising the app I was thinking of making it a PWA and stumbled upon the fact that we can't use SQLite with PWA which might cause few issues.

1. Storing Relational Data for offline: Available solutions like IndexedDB are non relational (I'm not sure why they are called structured and NoSQL at the same time). This seems like a huge problem, especially for an existing app which have offline features. If my understanding above is correct, I will require to modify all the sql queries and do something crazy as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8694941/conceptual-problems-with-indexeddb-relationships-etc) to make it work. Is it still the case in 2020? Is there an easier migration path that I could adopt?
2. Storage limit for offline: There is confusing [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593463/pwa-on-ios-and-offline-storage) on the limit of data that i can store in client side while a page is saved to the home-screen v/s while it's on web. I read pouch db [faq](https://pouchdb.com/faq.html) and mozilla [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria) which also tries explainig on the limits, but I'm still not sure what the limits are? What is real maximum limit on storage for offline if I can force the user to save the PWA to home-screen on ios? What alternatives do I have for feeding 500MB offline data to my PWA given that I can can restrict browsers, and ask user to do special setup(if required)?

NOTE: I want to keep it as pure PWA. So can't wrap it into an app and deploy.

Comment: Hi. Did you find any answers? how much storage space support pwa?

Comment: Apart from the links referred in question, you may also refer to the google's documentation on PWA. https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/live-data-in-the-service-worker